# Converting a hex digest to a long in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, hex, sha

How would I convert a hex string (say, a SHA256 digest) to a long in Clojure/Java?

This results in a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`:

```
(Long/parseLong "4590d31a9cf5eb30997501f82b1b8db051c01f7ea8a2c413343f2c1b9f5aa04e" 16)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `long` is only 64 bits. A SHA-256 digest has 256 bits (hence the name). So no, you can't (reversibly) perform that conversion.

If you just want (say) the bottom 64 bits, you could either take the last 16 hex digits and parse that, or you could convert the whole thing into a byte array and convert 8 bytes from that array into a long.

If you want the *whole* number, you should consider `BigInteger` instead. None of the primitive types in Java handle 256 bits.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ended up going the "last 16 hex digit" route.

Comment: Actually, taking the last 16 digits fails in some cases, e.g. `(Long/parseLong "aaf933f094e389e7" 16)`

Comment: @yayitswei: Well yes, you need to be careful around negative numbers - you might want to go via `BigInteger` anyway rather than using `parseLong`. (Or you could parse the last 15 digits first, and parse the other one separately, and combine them.) But I didn't feel it was worth going into detail on that when it wasn't clear what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

This works, resulting in a BigInteger:

```
(BigInteger. "4590d31a9cf5eb30997501f82b1b8db051c01f7ea8a2c413343f2c1b9f5aa04e" 16)
```

If I needed a long it would be a lossy conversion, as Jon pointed out above.